# iOS: How can I notify/alert the user when he/she suspends the app?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I'm tasked to implement a feature that sends qualified users a link to an online survey when they first suspend the app. Ideally I'd do this with a Notification of some type (e.g. local, push). Is there a way to have the app trigger a notification to the user when they suspend such that tapping it would open the survey link (perhaps via relaunching the app first)?

Answer (score 0):

In `AppDelegate`, you need to save whether or not the user has ever opened the app before.

**AppDelegate**

```
//make sure to import the framework
//additionally, if you want to customize the notification's UI,
//import the UserNotificationsUI
import UserNotifications

//default value is true, because it will be set false if this is not the first launch
var firstLaunch: Bool = true
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

//also make sure to include *UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate*
//in your class declaration of the AppDelegate
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

//get whether this is the very first launch
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let bool = defaults.object(forKey: "firstLaunch") as? Bool {
        firstLaunch = bool
    }
    defaults.set(false, forKey: "firstLaunch")
    defaults.synchronize()

    //ask the user to allow notifications
    //maybe do this some other place, where it is more appropriate
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in}

    return true
}

//schedule your notification when exiting the app, if necessary
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    //update the variable
    if let bool = defaults.object(forKey: "firstLaunch") as? Bool {
        firstLaunch = bool
    }
    if !firstLaunch {
        //abort mission if it's not the first launch
        return
    }
    //customize your notification's content
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Survey?"
    content.body = "Would you like to take a quick survey?"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    //schedule the notification
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "takeSurvey", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

At last, handle the response you got and open your link. That's it!

Comment: As you set firstLaunch = false in "didFinishLaunching" ... how could it ever be true in "didEnterBackground()"? Or am I missing something?

Comment: True that. Have you tried my code though? For me it automagically works. If not, you could just move those 2 lines to the `applicationDidEnterBackground()` right after the notification is being scheduled or after `firstLaunch` is being read. Let me know how that goes!